Can't drop connections from outside to access docker container
I have a container running gvm community edition. I recently installed it and it is working fine
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                         NAMES
55304d85f22f   greenbone/gsa:stable               "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   50 minutes ago   Up 49 minutes   $MY_IP:9392->80/tcp   greenbone-community-edition-gsa-1
c80c89c40a72   greenbone/gvmd:stable              "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   50 minutes ago   Up 49 minutes                                 greenbone-community-edition-gvmd-1
3bb3c3376446   greenbone/ospd-openvas:stable      "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   50 minutes ago   Up 49 minutes                                 greenbone-community-edition-ospd-openvas-1
9daf6e9bd124   greenbone/openvas-scanner:stable   "/bin/sh -c /usr/loc…"   50 minutes ago   Up 49 minutes                                 greenbone-community-edition-openvasd-1
1f7c12510a74   greenbone/redis-server             "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f /…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes                                 greenbone-community-edition-redis-server-1
4425e00821a6   greenbone/openvas-scanner:stable   "/bin/sh -c 'cat /et…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes                                 greenbone-community-edition-openvas-1
fd246a3d21c7   greenbone/pg-gvm:stable            "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes                                 greenbone-community-edition-pg-gvm-1

The issue i'm having is i want only my IP to access the container but i can't figure it out.
I tried dropping all connections with iptables on table DOCKER-USER, FORWARD, INPUT... and no success.
How could this be properly done?
